# Создание таблицы при помощи библиотеки netdxf

Tags: c#, autocad

Кто-нибудь создавал AutoCAD таблицу при помощи библиотеки netDxf?
Вроде как это можно сделать, но пока не могу разобраться, как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сайте http://netdxf.codeplex.com указан перечень примитивов, поддерживаемых библиотекой. Как видишь, на сегодняшний день таблицы в указанном перечне отсутствуют. На той же странице ниже указано, что таблицы AutoCAD будут импортироваться как вхождения блоков.

Comment: Спасибо. Просматривал сайт библиотеки, но этот момент пропустил.